# Shifting non-NA cells to the left

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

There are many NA's in my dataset and I need to shift all those cells (at row level) to the left.

Example- my dataframe:

```
    df=data.frame(x=c("l","m",NA,NA,"p"),y=c(NA,"b","c",NA,NA),z=c("u",NA,"w","x","y"))
    df
         x    y    z
    1    l <NA>    u
    2    m    b <NA>
    3 <NA>    c    w
    4 <NA> <NA>    x
    5    p <NA>    y
```

I want the above dataframe converted into this:

```
      x    y  z
    1 l    u NA
    2 m    b NA
    3 c    w NA
    4 x <NA> NA
    5 p    y NA
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the standard `apply` function:

```
df=data.frame(x=c("l","m",NA,NA,"p"),y=c(NA,"b","c",NA,NA),z=c("u",NA,"w","x","y"))
df2 = as.data.frame(t(apply(df,1, function(x) { return(c(x[!is.na(x)],x[is.na(x)]) )} )))
colnames(df2) = colnames(df)

> df
     x    y    z
1    l <NA>    u
2    m    b <NA>
3 <NA>    c    w
4 <NA> <NA>    x
5    p <NA>    y
> df2
  x    y    z
1 l    u <NA>
2 m    b <NA>
3 c    w <NA>
4 x <NA> <NA>
5 p    y <NA>
```

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @Richard Scriven for good observation

**A)** with `is.na` and `order`, `lapply` and `rbind` for aggregation

```
nosort.df<-do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(df),function(x) { z=df[x,][order(is.na(df[x,]))];colnames(z)<-c("x","y","z");return(z) } ))

> nosort.df
  x    y    z
1 l    u <NA>
2 m    b <NA>
3 c    w <NA>
4 x <NA> <NA>
5 p    y <NA>
```

**B)** if sorted rows are required:

with `sort`, `lapply` and `rbind`

```
sort.df<-do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(df),function(x) { z=sort(df[x,],na.last=TRUE);colnames(z)<-c("x","y","z");return(z) } ))

> sort.df
  x    y    z
1 l    u <NA>
2 b    m <NA>
3 c    w <NA>
4 x <NA> <NA>
5 p    y <NA>
```

Comment: Wait, you're sorting the row?  This will change the position of values that don't need to be changed.

Answer (score 5):

I have included a function for this task in my package `dedupewider` (available on CRAN). It allows to move `NA` to right, left or even top and bottom:

```
library(dedupewider)

df <- data.frame(x = c("l", "m", NA, NA, "p"),
                 y = c(NA, "b", "c", NA, NA),
                 z = c("u", NA, "w", "x", "y"))

na_move(df) # 'right' direction is by default

#>   x    y  z
#> 1 l    u NA
#> 2 m    b NA
#> 3 c    w NA
#> 4 x <NA> NA
#> 5 p    y NA
```

It implements the solution of reshaping data (from wide format to long and again to wide) and internally uses `data.table` functions. Thus it is significantly faster than standard solution using `apply`:

```
library(dedupewider)
library(microbenchmark)

df <- data.frame(x = c("l", "m", NA, NA, "p"),
                 y = c(NA, "b", "c", NA, NA),
                 z = c("u", NA, "w", "x", "y"))

df <- do.call(rbind, replicate(10000, df, simplify = FALSE))

apply_function <- function(df) {
  as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))))
}

microbenchmark(apply_function(df), na_move(df))

#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max
#>  apply_function(df) 289.2032 361.0178 475.65281 425.79355 545.6405 999.4086
#>         na_move(df)  51.0419  58.1426  75.32407  65.01445  92.8706 216.6384
```

Comment: Just want to add that if your use case involves substantial dataframes or data tables the na_move() function is even more performant I'm working with 3M+ rows and 9 columns to move around, the lapply function runs for >10 minutes whereas na_move() gets it done in 16 seconds

Answer (score 4):

There have been a number of duplicate questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651606) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70527301)) since this one was asked. I have collected (and improved) some of the more idiomatic answers and benchmarked them against my own `Rcpp` implementation.

For simplicity, I have compared functions that take as input and return as output a character matrix, *not* a data frame containing only character variables. You can always coerce from one to the other with `as.matrix` and `as.data.frame` (see bottom for example).

```r
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = '
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void shift_na_in_place(CharacterMatrix x)
{
  int m = x.nrow();
  int n = x.ncol();
  for (int i = 0, k = 0, k0 = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
      if (x[k] != NA_STRING) {
        x[k0] = x[k];
        k0 += m;
      }
      k += m;
    }
    while (k0 < k) {
      x[k0] = NA_STRING;
      k0 += m;
    }
    k = (k % m) + 1;
    k0 = k;
  }
  if (x.attr("dimnames") != R_NilValue) {
    List dn = x.attr("dimnames");
    dn[1] = R_NilValue;
    if (dn.attr("names") != R_NilValue) {
      CharacterVector ndn = dn.attr("names");
      ndn[1] = "";
    }
  }
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterMatrix shift_na(CharacterMatrix x)
{
  CharacterMatrix y = clone(x);
  shift_na_in_place(y);
  return y;
}
')
```

```r
f1 <- function(x) {
  t(apply(x, 1L, function(y) {r <- is.na(y); c(y[!r], y[r])}))
}
f2 <- function(x) {
  t(apply(x, 1L, function(y) y[order(is.na(y), method = "radix")]))
}
f3 <- function(x) {
  d <- dim(x)
  dn <- dimnames(x)
  matrix(x[order(row(x), is.na(x), method = "radix")],
         nrow = d[1L], ncol = d[2L], byrow = TRUE,
         dimnames = if (!is.null(dn)) c(dn[1L], list(NULL)))
}
f4 <- function(x) {
  d <- dim(x)
  dn <- dimnames(x)
  matrix(x[order(is.na(x) + (row(x) - 1L) * 2L + 1L, method = "radix")],
         nrow = d[1L], ncol = d[2L], byrow = TRUE,
         dimnames = if (!is.null(dn)) c(dn[1L], list(NULL)))
}
```

```r
set.seed(1L)
m <- 1e+05L
n <- 10L
x <- sample(c(letters, NA), size = m * n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(rep(1, 26), 13))
dim(x) <- c(m, n)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(shift_na(x), f1(x), f2(x), f3(x), f4(x), check = "identical")
```

```
Unit: milliseconds
        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 shift_na(x)  10.04959  10.32019  10.82935  10.41968  10.60104  22.69412   100
       f1(x) 141.95959 150.83875 180.49025 167.01266 211.52478 248.07587   100
       f2(x) 722.27211 759.75710 780.69368 773.26920 797.01253 857.07905   100
       f3(x)  18.45201  19.15436  22.47760  21.59577  22.40543  66.47121   100
       f4(x)  30.03168  31.62765  35.22960  33.92801  35.06384  85.92661   100
```

The dedicated `Rcpp` implementation `shift_na` is fastest, as you might expect, but `f3` and `f4` are not much slower. A few finer points:

- `f1` and `f2` call `apply`, which is built on an R `for` loop, so it is not surprising that they are slow.
- `f3` and `f4` have to allocate memory for `is.na(x)` and `row(x)`, which could be a hindrance for large enough `x`.
- `f3` is faster than `f4` because the `"radix"` sort uses a faster algorithm when the range (maximum minus minimum) of the integer vector being sorted is less than 100000 (see `?sort`). Here, the ranges are:

  ```
                            is.na(x):      1
                              row(x):  99999
  is.na(x) + (row(x) - 1L) * 2L + 1L: 199999
  ```
- `shift_na(x)` creates a copy of `x` and modifies the copy in place. If you cannot or do not want to allocate memory for a copy because `x` is very large, then you can do `shift_na_in_place(x)` to modify `x` in place.
- `shift_na_in_place` should be preferred over `shift_na` if you have a data frame `data` containing character variables, rather than a character matrix. In this situation, there is no need to preserve the intermediate `as.matrix(data)`; it can be modified in place:

  ```r
  x <- as.matrix(data)
  shift_na_in_place(x)
  newdata <- as.data.frame(x)
  ```

Answer (score 2):

If you won't get shorter answer, this should help:

```
df=data.frame(x=c("l","m",NA,NA,"p"),y=c(NA,"b","c",NA,NA),z=c("u",NA,"w","x","y"))
sapply(df,as.character)


for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  sub <- df[i,c(which(!is.na(df[i,])),which(is.na(df[i,])))] 
  colnames(sub) <- colnames(df)
  df[i,] <- sub
}
```

Comment: The three `as.character` statements could be combined with `sapply(df,as.character)`

Answer (score 2):

Another answer with shorter syntax:

```
df=data.frame(x=c("l","m",NA,NA,"p"),y=c(NA,"b","c",NA,NA),z=c("u",NA,"w","x","y"))

      x   y   z  
[1,] "l" NA  "u"
[2,] "m" "b" NA 
[3,] NA  "c" "w"
[4,] NA  NA  "x"
[5,] "p" NA  "y"



sorted.df <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))])))

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "l"  "u"  NA  
[2,] "m"  "b"  NA  
[3,] "c"  "w"  NA  
[4,] "x"  NA   NA  
[5,] "p"  "y"  NA
```

Comment: The question mentions shifting of cells and not ordering. You will find the question's output df different from yours.

Comment: This returns a matrix while the OP expects a data.frame.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `pmap` function from `purrr` package to great advantage here:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  pmap(., ~ c(c(...)[!is.na(c(...))], c(...)[is.na(c(...))])) %>%
  exec(rbind, !!!.) %>%
  as_tibble()

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  x     z     y    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 l     u     NA   
2 m     b     NA   
3 c     w     NA   
4 x     NA    NA   
5 p     y     NA
```

Answer (score -6):

If you don't want to use VBA, you can try the following steps.

```
1. Select your dataset
2. Replace NA will empty cells
3. press F5 and select blanks ok
4. right click on any of the selection and delete (left)
```

I hope this helps.