# How to move data from one column to another in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning, columnsorting

I am trying to move data from one column to another, due to the underlying forms being filled out incorrectly.

In the form it asks for information on a household and asks for their age(AGE) and gender(SEX) for each member, allowing up to 5 people per household. However some users have filled in information for person 1,3 and 4, but not filled in any info for person 2 because they filled out person 2 incorrectly, crossed out the details and have filled person 2 details into the person 3 boxes etc.

The data looks like this (ref 1 and 5 are correct in this data, all others are incorrect)

```
df <- data.frame(
  ref = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  AGE1 = c(45, 36, 26, 47, 24, NA),
  AGE2 = c(NA, 24, NA, 13, 57, 28),
  AGE3 = c(NA, NA, 35, NA, NA, 26),
  AGE4 = c(NA, NA, 15, 11, NA, NA),
  AGE5 = c(NA, 15, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  SEX1 = c("M", "F", "M", "M", "M", NA),
  SEX2 = c(NA, "M", NA, "F", "F", "F"),
  SEX3 = c(NA, NA, "M", NA, NA, "M"),
  SEX4 = c(NA, NA, "F", "F", NA, NA),
  SEX5 = c(NA, "F", NA, NA, NA, NA)
)
```

This is what the table looks like currently
(I have replaced NA with - to make reading easier)

| ref | AGE1 | AGE2 | AGE3 | AGE4 | AGE5 | SEX1 | SEX2 | SEX3 | SEX4 | SEX5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | - | - | - | - | M | - | - | - | - |
| 2 | 36 | 24 | - | - | 15 | F | M | - | - | F |
| 3 | 26 | - | 35 | 15 | - | M | - | M | F | - |
| 4 | 47 | 13 | - | 11 | - | M | F | - | F | - |
| 5 | 24 | 57 | - | - | - | M | F | - | - | - |
| 6 | - | 28 | 26 | - | - | - | F | M | - | - |

but i would like it to look like this

| ref | AGE1 | AGE2 | AGE3 | AGE4 | AGE5 | SEX1 | SEX2 | SEX3 | SEX4 | SEX5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | - | - | - | - | M | - | - | - | - |
| 2 | 36 | 24 | 15 | - | - | F | M | F | - | - |
| 3 | 26 | 35 | 15 | - | - | M | M | F | - | - |
| 4 | 47 | 13 | 11 | - | - | M | F | F | - | - |
| 5 | 24 | 57 | - | - | - | M | F | - | - | - |
| 6 | 28 | 26 | - | - | - | F | M | - | - | - |

Is there a way of correcting this using `dplyr`? If not, is there another way in R of correcting the data

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285215/shifting-non-na-cells-to-the-left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. The approach involves pivoting the data to longer format, sorting the `NA` values to the end, renumbering the column names, and the pivoting to wide form again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <-  data.frame(ref, AGE1, AGE2, AGE3, AGE4, AGE5,
                  SEX1, SEX2, SEX3, SEX4, SEX5)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("AGE"), as.character)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(2:11) %>%
  separate(name, into = c("cat", "num"), 3) %>%
  arrange(is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(ref, cat) %>%
  mutate(num = seq_along(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(cat) %>%
  unite(name, cat, num, sep = "") %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ref) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("AGE"), as.numeric))


# A tibble: 6 x 11
    ref  AGE1  AGE2  AGE3  AGE4  AGE5 SEX1  SEX2  SEX3  SEX4  SEX5 
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1    45    NA    NA    NA    NA M     NA    NA    NA    NA   
2     2    36    24    15    NA    NA F     M     F     NA    NA   
3     3    26    35    15    NA    NA M     M     F     NA    NA   
4     4    47    13    11    NA    NA M     F     F     NA    NA   
5     5    24    57    NA    NA    NA M     F     NA    NA    NA   
6     6    28    26    NA    NA    NA F     M     NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: This works well for getting the order the same as it was initially too. Why do you need to convert the age variables into a character and then back to a numeric?

Comment: The pivot gets messy if the data types are not the same.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using `dplyr` and `tidyr` library.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ref, 
               names_to = c('.value', 'num'), 
               names_pattern = '([A-Z]+)(\\d+)') %>%
  arrange(ref, AGE, SEX) %>%
  group_by(ref) %>%
  mutate(num = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = num, values_from = c(AGE, SEX)) 

#    ref AGE_1 AGE_2 AGE_3 AGE_4 AGE_5 SEX_1 SEX_2 SEX_3 SEX_4 SEX_5
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     1    45    NA    NA    NA    NA M     NA    NA    NA    NA   
#2     2    15    24    36    NA    NA F     M     F     NA    NA   
#3     3    15    26    35    NA    NA F     M     M     NA    NA   
#4     4    11    13    47    NA    NA F     F     M     NA    NA   
#5     5    24    57    NA    NA    NA M     F     NA    NA    NA   
#6     6    26    28    NA    NA    NA M     F     NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: This is so smart using `pivot_longer` + `pivot_wider`, cheers, upvoted!

Comment: Thomas, Ronak thanks both for your help. 
Because I want to keep the order of the people as the form was filled out (i.e. if I had p1,p3,p4 completed i want p3 to fill p2 and p4 to fill p3) i got rid of the arrange(ref,AGE,SEX) line of the code. 
It appears to work correctly, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something?

The actual data has a lot more columns than what i put on here, would you recommend just selecting out the age and sex columns, doing this method and then left_joining back into the data by the reference number?

Answer (score 1):

Try the base code below

```
u1 <- reshape(
  setNames(df, sub("(\\d)", ".\\1", names(df))),
  direction = "long",
  idvar = "ref",
  varying = -1
)

u2  <- reshape(
  transform(
    u1[with(u1, order(is.na(AGE), is.na(SEX))), ],
    time = ave(time, ref, FUN = seq_along)
  ),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "ref"
)

out <- u2[match(names(df),sub("\\.","",names(u2)))]
```

and you will get

```
> out
    ref AGE.1 AGE.2 AGE.3 AGE.4 AGE.5 SEX.1 SEX.2 SEX.3 SEX.4 SEX.5
1.1   1    45    NA    NA    NA    NA     M  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2.1   2    36    24    15    NA    NA     F     M     F  <NA>  <NA>
3.1   3    26    35    15    NA    NA     M     M     F  <NA>  <NA>
4.1   4    47    13    11    NA    NA     M     F     F  <NA>  <NA>
5.1   5    24    57    NA    NA    NA     M     F  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
6.2   6    28    26    NA    NA    NA     F     M  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

## data

```
df <- data.frame(
  ref = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  AGE1 = c(45, 36, 26, 47, 24, NA),
  AGE2 = c(NA, 24, NA, 13, 57, 28),
  AGE3 = c(NA, NA, 35, NA, NA, 26),
  AGE4 = c(NA, NA, 15, 11, NA, NA),
  AGE5 = c(NA, 15, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  SEX1 = c("M", "F", "M", "M", "M", NA),
  SEX2 = c(NA, "M", NA, "F", "F", "F"),
  SEX3 = c(NA, NA, "M", NA, NA, "M"),
  SEX4 = c(NA, NA, "F", "F", NA, NA),
  SEX5 = c(NA, "F", NA, NA, NA, NA)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using package `dedupewider`:

```
library(dedupewider)

df <- data.frame(
  ref = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  AGE1 = c(45, 36, 26, 47, 24, NA),
  AGE2 = c(NA, 24, NA, 13, 57, 28),
  AGE3 = c(NA, NA, 35, NA, NA, 26),
  AGE4 = c(NA, NA, 15, 11, NA, NA),
  AGE5 = c(NA, 15, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  SEX1 = c("M", "F", "M", "M", "M", NA),
  SEX2 = c(NA, "M", NA, "F", "F", "F"),
  SEX3 = c(NA, NA, "M", NA, NA, "M"),
  SEX4 = c(NA, NA, "F", "F", NA, NA),
  SEX5 = c(NA, "F", NA, NA, NA, NA)
)

age_moved <- na_move(df, cols = names(df)[grepl("^AGE\\d$", names(df))]) # 'right' direction is by default

sex_moved <- na_move(age_moved, cols = names(df)[grepl("^SEX\\d$", names(df))])

sex_moved

#>   ref AGE1 AGE2 AGE3 AGE4 AGE5 SEX1 SEX2 SEX3 SEX4 SEX5
#> 1   1   45   NA   NA   NA   NA    M <NA> <NA>   NA   NA
#> 2   2   36   24   15   NA   NA    F    M    F   NA   NA
#> 3   3   26   35   15   NA   NA    M    M    F   NA   NA
#> 4   4   47   13   11   NA   NA    M    F    F   NA   NA
#> 5   5   24   57   NA   NA   NA    M    F <NA>   NA   NA
#> 6   6   28   26   NA   NA   NA    F    M <NA>   NA   NA
```